# EditText not showing soft keyboard after Dialog closed

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have a form on my app filled with EditTexts. Somewhere in the middle of the form, there is a Date Picker Dialog ([See here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)). The user can go from EditText to EditText by hitting the "next" button on the soft keyboard. When the user gets to the Date Picker, the keyboard closes and the dialog is shown. When the user selects a date, I'd like the next EditText in the form to gain focus and show the keyboard again.

What I currently have is the date is set, the dialog is closed, the next EditText gets focus and the cursor is shown, but the keyboard will not open. I have tried various methods to try to get the keyboard open, but none appear to work. Here's what some of my code

```
RelativeLayout next = rows.get(currentRow);
next.requestFocus();
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```

Here, I am getting the next RelativeLayout from a list of RelativeLayouts (`rows`). I request focus for this row, then I ask for the soft keyboard to open. This does not work.

I have also tried this, in my EditText's `onFocusChangedListener`:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
...
String s = text.getText().toString().trim();
if (hasFocus){
    ...
    imm.showSoftInput((EditText)v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is a late answer but I faced a similar problem with my app. In my app there are some editText elements and a cancel button which pops up an alert dialog (with message are you sure to cancel? ). After the dialog is dismissed the keyboard not appear, even if the cursor is in the editText. So I created a two Runnable instace (one for clear focus, one for request focus on element) and call them when it is needed. Eg. when the dialog shows up call the clear focus, when dissappear call the request focus one. And finally it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding following in your activity manifest file?

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"

This would make your keyboard always visible in that activity.

Comment: I don't want the keyboard to always be visible. For example, when the Date Picker dialog is visible, I would like the keyboard to close and then re-open again when the dialog is dismissed.